# Overhead of finding the length of a sequence in python?

Tags: python, optimization

I was going to find the length of a sequence in **python3** and found that [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is now of `<class type>` not `<type builtin_function_or_method>`

Being so, the `range` call seems to create a generator in memory without the overhead of creating a `list` and populating it as in **python2** (please correct me if I'm misunderstanding or I am wrong about this).

My question now is, would there be any noticeable improvement for calculating the length of a sequence where, I call `len(range(start, stop, step))` instead of calculating `int(math.ceil((stop - start) / step))`.

This is a rough example of what I would be doing:

```
s = list(range(limit))
s[1] = 0
for i in range(2, sqrtn + 1):
    if s[i]:
        s[i*i: limit: i] = [0] * len(range(i*i, limit, i)) # call to range
```

Would the above be actually more efficient then calculating the length?

```
from math import ceil

s = list(range(limit))
s[1] = 0
for i in range(2, sqrtn + 1):
if s[i]:
    s[i*i: limit: i] = [0] * int(math.ceil((limit - i*i) / i)) # no range call
```

Comment: in python 3, `range` is not a generator. And since it is a class, I doubt that creating a class instance is faster than doing a simple arithmetic operation.

Comment: @RNar The number of names you import has no bearing on the execution time of the `import` statement. The module is always imported in full; qualified imports only hide the unwanted names.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson noted, good to know. deleted the comment

Comment: @RNar: All things in Python are instances of classes you know. Even `int`. `int` gets some optimization, but it's still a class, and its instances are still created and destroyed constantly during basic math operations.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I guess my wording is really unclear in that, but I definitely meant specifically a class instance of `range` :/

Comment: @RNar: The point is, a `range` instance doesn't really involve a lot of work to construct, and it does mean that, if the values all fit in a signed `size_t`, the math to calculate the length can be done in C as a bunch of raw CPU math instructions. `int` math is optimized so operations on small enough `int`s convert to C types, use the raw CPU math, then return a new `int` (though I believe there is a free list for small `int`s, so no allocation occurs most of the time). Point is, it's not at all intuitive which would be faster; small tweaks could make one win over another.

Comment: Most of the work to make a `range` is just loading the name `range` and constructing the `tuple` of arguments the C level interface receives, and being nice by accepting any `numbers.Integral` (where `int` is special cased in some math ops to bypass a lot of dynamic dispatch); very little of the work is about actually making the `range` object itself.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this was my reservation and reason for asking this quesion to start.  The calls to `int` and `ceil` vs. just `range` but, I wasn't sure if the former would incur anything close to the latter or maybe the opposite that `range`  is optimized to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes, in practice, no. All timings on Windows x64 build of CPython 3.5.0 (specific times irrelevant; the relative times for each approach are what matter):

```
>>> from math import ceil
>>> start, stop, step = 100*100, 100000, 100
>>> min(timeit.repeat('(stop - start + (step - 1)) // step', 'from __main__ import start, stop, step', number=100000))
0.016031580173375914
>>> min(timeit.repeat('ceil((stop - start) / step)', 'from __main__ import start, stop, step, ceil', number=100000))
0.024184756985505373
>>> min(timeit.repeat('len(range(start, stop, step))', 'from __main__ import start, stop, step', number=100000))
0.03917228338013956
```

I've run those tests with a few different endpoints; if the values get large enough that the math can't be done in `Py_ssize_t`, the `range` and `ceil` approaches get closer together (`ceil` slows down), but the pure `int` math approach wins every test I've run. And both `range` and `ceil` have problems; for very large numbers, `range` will throw `OverflowError` (it can't have more elements than a `Py_ssize_t` can represent), and `ceil` (or rather, the float division before the `ceil`) will have floating point accuracy errors as you exceed ~53 bit values. The pure `int` math is both fast and reliable, and should probably be preferred.

That said, other Python interpreters (PyPy, IronPython, Jython, Cython) can special case stuff like `range` (and integer math for that matter), and could easily have completely different performance characteristics.

The real overhead here is not the `len` calculation. `range` actually computes the length and caches it internally during construction; retrieving it is as close to free as any named function call gets (and the same is true of all built-in sequences; at worst they have to construct a Python level `int` from a C level `int`, but all math operations do the same thing). The actual cost to retrieve the length:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat('len(r)', 'from __main__ import start, stop, step; r = range(start, stop, step)', number=100000))
0.0076398965929911355
```

Comment: I've run these tests several times and get very similiar results.  Funny though that on a couple the `ceil` beats out the pure `int`

Comment: @tijko: That will happen on occasion, but it's most likely to happen in cases where the numbers are large enough (and therefore `int` math involves array based math, where `float` is always native CPU `double` math) that the result of the `ceil` calculation is _wrong_; fastest to the wrong answer is still wrong. Example to try out: `start, stop, step = (1 << 250) + 7, (1 << 256) + 11, (1 << 200) - 3`, `ceil((stop - start) / step)`, `(stop - start + (step - 1)) // step`. `range` gets this one right, but for smaller `step`, it eventually starts raising `OverflowError`.